# vim backward search and replace before the matched pattern

Tags: vim

I'm enjoying vim, and its powerful search and replace command. However, I need to perform a complex research and substitute, like this one:

1) find the first occurrence of "field.h" and delete the line
2) from the deleted line search backwards up to a line containing "foo.h" (this search has to be case insensitive), and put a new line just before it containing "include 'io.h'"

3) repeat this operation for every occurrance of "field.h" in the file

Now, I know how to delete all the lines in a file matching a pattern, and how to insert a new line before a pattern, but I don't knonw how to all of this combined.

For point 1 above, I would do `:g/field.h/d`,  while for point 2 something like `:g/"foo.h"/s/#include "io.h"\r&/g` should work...

As an example,  the starting file could be:

```
"foo.h"

lines of text, they can be also empty lines
#include "field.h"
other text
```

and the resulting file should be:

```
#include "io.h"
"foo.h"

lines of text, they can be also empty lines
other text
```

Some can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the job of a vim macro. It would help if you provide a small sample

Comment: yeah, add a sample showing before and after.. also add the commands you are doing individually, it'll help others to use it or even suggest improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:g/\c"field.h"/d | ?"foo.h"?norm! O#include "io.h"
```

should work. Transforms

```
"foo.h"

lines of text, they can be also empty lines
#include "field.h"
other text

"foo.h"

#include "FIELD.h"
```

into

```
#include "io.h"
"foo.h"

lines of text, they can be also empty lines
other text

#include "io.h"
"foo.h"
```

Breaking it down:

- `:g/\c"foo.h"/` : for all lines matching "foo.h" (`\c` for case-insentivity)
- `d`: delete
- `|` : chain with another command
- `?"foo.h"?`: backward search for the previous `"foo.h"`
- `norm!`: run the following input as in normal mode (`!` to remove all mappings, you might not need/want this)
- `O`: Enter insert mode on the line above (do not use a `-` modifier to the search, it would fail to go above the first line)
- `#include "io.h"`: write #include "io.h"

Comment: Great!! I've just realized that sometimes "foo.h" is not followed by a an #include "field.h", but with this command it should not be a problem, isn't it?

Comment: Those `"foo.h"` won't have `#include "io.h"` above them, but I'm guessing that what you want?